# python fab open_shell do not continue the execution after ping does not answer on the switch

Tags: python, fabric, switching

I am trying to create a script to configure, test, and unconfigure the interface VLAN on my farm. I am using Fabric and am running open_shell function to run multiple commands. The first part works well to configure the interface, but when it comes to testing with a ping request, it stops working. Let me enumerate the tasks:

1. Create the interface VLAN (works)
2. Put an IP address on the interface VLAN (works)
3. Exit from interface VLAN (works)
4. Run the ping to an IP address (works)
5. Do other things: (does not work)

The 5th step does not run. What I realised is that the IP destination is not answered, and this is on purpose for the test. The destination IP is off. The script stops on the switch prompt. With the ping fail, the execution could not continue any more.

Is there something that I can do to force the execution to continue?